# how to specify two values for the second argument for lodash orderBy?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Could anyone help me how to realize the following case: I have an array with objects, every object has field `createEL`, and some of them have `updateEl`.

My task is to sort all the elements with `updateEl` if it's available, otherwise sort by `createEl`

my current option:

```
orderBy(myData, ['updateEl','createEl'], 'desc)
```

I wonder  if it's correct for cases if I don't have `updateEl` option.

Thanks in advance for every support

Comment: No, that's not what this does. It sorts by `updateEl`, and when `updateEl` is the same it sorts within the group by `createEl`.

Comment: I'm not sure I got you, I have createEl date in every object and updateEl in some of them, and I need to sort of choose updateEl it it's available, or createEl

Comment: I know that's what you want to do. I was explaining what your code actually does.

Comment: So what is not working with what you have?

Comment: Now I have scenario when all the objects have updateEl date, but I'm not sure about case there are both types of objects in my array - with updateEl date and without, and I want some experienced in lodash guy to help me a bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function that returns either `updateEl` or `createEl` as the field to order by.

```
orderBy(myData, el => el.updateEl || el.createEl)
```